# Yajra Laravel Datatable - Merge Column values

Tags: laravel, datatables

I have included Yajra Datatables in my Laravel Project and its working fine.

The Problem is that I need to merge 3 column values and show them as 1 and allow search at the same time.

How do i do that?

I was able to use the render function and display data in a single column. But then how to search?

Sample Mysql table:

```
student_master(fname,mname,lname)
```

On the javascript i have:

```
columns: [
    {data: 'thiscanbeanything', render:function ( data, type, row ) {                        
                return row.fname+row.mname+row.lname;
            }},
]
```

My Ajax function on the controller looks like this

```
 $results = DB::table("student_master")
            ->select(['fname', 'mname', 'lname']);

    return Datatables::of($results)                        
                    ->make(true);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try following code

On server Side

```
$results = DB::table("student_master")
        ->select(['fname', 'mname', 'lname']);

return Datatables::of($results)
      ->addColumn('mergeColumn', function($row){
      return $row->fname.$row->mname.$row->lname;
})
->make(true);
```

Javascript Side

```
` columns: [
        {data: 'mergeColumn', name: 'mergeColumn', searchable: false, sortable : false, visible:true},
        {data: 'fname', name: 'fname', searchable: true, sortable : true, visible:false},
        {data: 'mname', name: 'mname', searchable: true, sortable : true, visible:false},
        {data: 'lname', name: 'lname', searchable: true, sortable : true, visible:false},
    ],`
```

**Above code is not tested** but you can try. If you have any problem then let me know.

Comment: Is there any way to make the sort working in this scenario ??

Answer (score 0):

Server side

```
    $results = DB::table("student_master")
    ->select([
        DB::raw('CONCAT(fname, " ", mname, " ", lname) as name'),
    ]);

    return Datatables::of($results)
    ->filterColumn('name', function($query, $keyword) {
        $query->whereRaw('CONCAT(fname, " ", mname, " ", lname) like ?', ["%{$keyword}%"]);
    })
    ->make(true);
```

JS

```
 columns: [
            { data: 'name'},
        ]
```

Now you can search and sort