# yajra datables - Merge Column values orderable not working Laravel

Tags: laravel

it does not work when clicking on the column header nothing changed no sorting at all !!

```
public function dataTable($query)
{
    return datatables()
        ->eloquent($query)
        ->addColumn('customer_name', function($customer){
            return $customer->first_name.' '.$customer->last_name;
        })
        
        })->rawColumns(['createdAt', 'action']);
}
```

sorting and search does not working.

```
    protected function getColumns()
    {
     return [
         'id', 
         'customer_name'=>[
           'data'=>'customer_name',
         ]
     ];
    }
```

Comment: i'think this may solve your answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272478/yajra-laravel-datatable-merge-column-values

Answer (score 1):

i'think sorting and search not working in concate column yajra datables.